# What does "File BauProf" mean?

Tags: citations, thesis

I am doing some research on Nigeria during its colonial period and as a result I have found the following thesis by Uyilawa Usuanlele called "[Poverty and welfare in colonial nigeria, 1900-1954](https://bac-lac.on.worldcat.org/oclc/1032923911)" very interesting.

One of the quotes the author uses is then referenced by the following ([Page 129](https://central.bac-lac.gc.ca/.item?id=TC-OKQ-13884&op=pdf&app=Library#page=137)):

> <sup>365</sup> Quoted from File BauProf 1356 in Abubakar, “Health under Colonialism: A Study of British Colonialism and its Health Policies in Bauchi Province, 1900-1960” Thesis, 264.

Thanks to [other Journals](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41857131) referencing the same thesis I was able to track it down to [Ahmadu Bello University Library](https://library.abu.edu.ng/) where its listed in its library catalog: [Health under colonialism: a study of the impact of British colonialism and its health policies in Bauchi province 1900-1960](http://catalog.abu.edu.ng/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=19697)

While I try and track down an electronic version of that thesis does anyone know what "File BauProf 1356" means? Could it maybe be an internal university system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a document K. Brunk" *Zum Landnutzungswandel in der südlichen Sudanzone am Beispiel des Bauchi State (Nordost-Nigeria)*, Berichte des Sonderforschungbereichs 268, Bd. 5, Frankfurt a.M. 1995: 51-67 [here](https://publikationen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/frontdoor/index/index/year/2006/docId/1881). The relevance is that the document has a bibliography with named categories. There are several "Bau Prof" references listed under the heading "Unveröffentlichte Archivunterlagen des National Archive Kaduna (NAK)", which loosely translates to "Unpublished archival records from the National Archive Kaduna (NAK)". Based on [this website](https://nationalarchivesnigeriakaduna.wordpress.com/list-of-record-groups/) for said national archive, I would guess that "BauProf" / "Bau Prof" may refer to their "BAUCHI PROVINCE RECORD GROUP" and that 1356 is a record number within that group. Either way, I suggest you consider contacting the NAK.